# How to make pivot table for non numeric column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying trying to extract records that are PO numbers associated to filename in a table. One filename can have up to five PO numbers. 
The table looks like:

```
ID  Filename             PO#          
-----------------------------------
1   file1                 001      
2   file1                 002         
3   file1                 003        
4   file1                 004    
5   file2                 001
6   file2                 002   
7   file3                 001 
.
.
.
```

What I want is:

```
Filename             PO#1    PO#2   PO#3   PO#4   PO#5          
-----------------------------------------------------------  
file1                001     002     003    004
file2                001     002  
file2                001
```

I tried Pivot.

Here is my code:

```
    SELECT [1] AS PO1, [2] AS PO2, [3] AS PO3, [4] AS PO4,[5] AS PO5
    From 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY filename ORDER BY [ID] 
    ASC) AS Row#, *
    FROM 1) as t
    PIVOT (
    max(PO)
    FOR Row#ByFileName IN ([1],[2], [3],[4],[5])) AS PivotTable
```

However, the result is

```
Filename             PO#1    PO#2   PO#3   PO#4   PO#5          
-----------------------------------------------------------  
file1                  001
file1                 null    002   null   null   null
file1                 null    null   003   null   null        
file1                 null    null  null    004   null   
file2                  001
file2                 null    002   null   null   null       
file3                  001
.
.
```

I also tried using stuff and  xml path to combine multiple rows into one row, and substring to split one column into multiple columns. But I could not get what I wnant.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation instead :

```
select filename,
       max(case when seq = 1 then po end) as [PO#1],
       . . . 
       max(case when seq = 5 then po end) as [PO#5]
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by filename order by id) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by filename;
```